# Parsing JSON Request failed using serialize();

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

The code below,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var value = $('#button input').val();
        var name = $('#button input').attr('name');

        $('#button input').remove();
        $('#button').html('<a href="#" class="cssSubmitButton" rel=' + name + '>' + value + '</a>');

        //global vars
        var form = $("#customForm");
        var name = $("#name");
        var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
        var email = $("#email");

        var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");


        //On blur
        name.blur(validateName);
        email.blur(validateEmail);

        //On key press
        name.keyup(validateName);
        email.keyup(validateEmail);
        //On Submitting
        $('#button a').on('click', function () {                    

            var link = $(this);
            if(validateName() & validateEmail())
            {
                var link = $(this);
                var str = $("form").serialize();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : 'load.php',
                    data: str,  
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: 'false',
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        link.addClass('loading');                   
                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        link.removeClass('loading');
                        $('#button').css('display','none');     
                        $('#success').css('display','block');

                    },
                    error:function(x,e){
                        if(x.status==0)
                        {
                            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                        }
                        else if(x.status==404)
                        {
                            alert('Requested URL not found.');
                        }
                        else if(x.status==500)
                        {
                            alert('Internel Server Error.');
                        }
                        else if(e=='parsererror')
                        {
                            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                        }
                        else if(e=='timeout')
                        {
                            alert('Request Time out.');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
                        }
                    }       
                });

                return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });


        //validation functions
        function validateEmail(){
            //testing regular expression
            var a = $("#email").val();
            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
            //if it's valid email
            if(filter.test(a)){
                email.removeClass("error");
                emailInfo.text("Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!");
                emailInfo.removeClass("error");
                return true;
            }
            //if it's NOT valid
            else{
                email.addClass("error");
                emailInfo.text("Stop cowboy! Type a valid e-mail please :P");
                emailInfo.addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validateName(){
            //if it's NOT valid
            if(name.val().length < 4){
                name.addClass("error");
                nameInfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
                nameInfo.addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
            //if it's valid
            else{
                name.removeClass("error");
                nameInfo.text("What's your name?");
                nameInfo.removeClass("error");
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

My HTML forum:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="subscribeForm" name="subscribeForm">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Name: </label><input type="text" class="effect" name="name" id="name"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="nameInfo">What's your name?</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label>Email: </label><input type="text" class="effect" name="email" id="email"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="emailInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribeForm"/>
    </div>
    <div id="success">
        <strong>Data Saved Successfully.</strong>
    </div>
</form>
```

Its giving me the error: Parsing JSON Request failed.

This is what I get in firebug,

```
load.php?name=asdf&email=ASDF%40gmail.com
```

this is my php code

```
<?php
sleep(3);
echo parse_str($_POST['str']);
?>
```

Comment: Is JSONP what you want? the url seems to be pointing to the same server... no need for overhead.

Comment: You are expecting JSONP, of course it will be wrapped in a callback function ?

Comment: Where in your code are you getting that line?

Comment: @AlejandroIván oops sorry updated the code

Comment: By looking your code, you have several errors. The major one is this one: "type: 'GET'", but in your PHP you're using $_POST. It's not necessary to send JSON to the PHP script, it will take the POST values from the AJAX request. The other side (from PHP to the Javascript) is better to use JSON ( $ret = array(...); echo json_encode($ret); )

Comment: Yeah, Send data through post. On server side use urldecode for converting email field, if it is still url encoded.

Comment: Not necessary. POST data is always sent URL-encoded (that's the way it's sent through the HTTP protocol). When managing it with a scripting engine (like PHP), it's that engine the one that automatically transforms those URL-encoded strings into some human-readable ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestions:**

1. Change '`data: str`' to  `data: {str:str}`
2. Change `parse_str($_POST['str']);` to `parse_str($_GET['str']);`
   Because, you are using '**GET**' method in **ajax**.
3. `parse_str` `converts all the query string in php var`. So after,
   `parse_str($_GET['str'])` you can show user name by `echo $name;`
4. You are using **json** with **ajax**, thus you have to **return proper json
   data** from url, use below example in load.php

Then, you can get name from **AJAX** response by **data.name**

```
<?php
parse_str($_GET['str']);
echo json_encode(array(
    'name' => $name
));
?>

//or

<?php
parse_str($_GET['str'], $response);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.serializeArray()` method:

```
var str = $("form").serializeArray();
```

Comment: Would that help with the JSONP ?

Comment: @YD1m added in the question

Comment: You should to return correct responce in jsonp format. Something like `$responce = array("responce"=>"successfull");
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($responce).')';`

Comment: @YD1m I am sorry but it was json and not jsonp I have updated the question.

Comment: ok, change last line of code from my previous comment for `echo json_encode($responce);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'load.php',
            data: str,  
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                link.addClass('loading');                   
            },

            success: function(data) {
                link.removeClass('loading');
                $('#button').css('display','none');     
                $('#success').css('display','block');
                var json = JSON.parse(data);                    
                alert(json.response); // Here you get the value

            },
            error:function(x,e){
                if(x.status==0)
                {
                    alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                }
                else if(x.status==404)
                {
                    alert('Requested URL not found.');
                }
                else if(x.status==500)
                {
                    alert('Internel Server Error.');
                }
                else if(e=='parsererror')
                {
                    alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                }
                else if(e=='timeout')
                {
                    alert('Request Time out.');
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
                }
            }
```

According to the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), **dataType** is the kind of data you're expecting **back** from the server, not the data being sent to it. It's enough to use POST and send the form serialization directly, because serialization IS the actual format for HTTP requests data. It will be transformed directly to $_POST values.

On the server side:

```
<?php
    sleep(3);
    $str = $_POST['str'];

    // Do whatever processing you need here with $str...

    // Set an array containing the response (it will be translated to JSON later)
    // You can use any kind of array, then you'll access the values like this in Javascript:
    // var resp = JSON.parse(data);
    // alert( resp.response );
    // or: alert( resp.whateverKeyYouUsed );
    $ret = array( "response" => "Some response message." );

    // Because the script is expecting a JSON response, encode the array and print it
    // The response would be something like {"response":"Some response message."} which is JSON
    echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```